# Regrouping pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How can I make this dataframe:

```
datecreated  timestamp  value  
2022-11-15      1       4000
2022-11-15      2       3900
2022-11-15      3       3850
2022-11-15      4       3810
2022-11-15      5       3790
```

to become:

```
    datecreated     1     2     3     4     5
0   2022-11-15      4000  3900  3850  3810  3790
```

I tried:

```
df = df.pivot(index='datecreated', columns='timestamp', values='value')
```

and the result is:

```
timestamp       1       2       3       4      5
datecreated                                                                  
2022-11-15      4000    3900    3850    3810   3790
```

Reset index:

```
timestamp datecreated       1       2       3  ...
0         2022-11-15        4000.0  3900.0  3850.0...
```

Comment: I believe that's how the ```index``` is displayed. If you ```reset_index()``` after your pivot it should be fine.

Comment: @sophocles i edited my question with reset index

Comment: `timestamp` becomes the name of the columns, probably chaining with `.rename_axis(columns=None)` would clean this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're seeing is just the column's axis name being automatically set to `timestamp` because of your pivot. This can be remedied by renaming the axis:

```
out = (df.pivot(index='datecreated', 
                columns='timestamp', 
                values='value')
         .reset_index()
         .rename_axis(columns=None))
print(out)
```

Output:

```
  datecreated     1     2     3     4     5
0  2022-11-15  4000  3900  3850  3810  3790
```